# mobX - Filter countries in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobx

I have an array of 3 countries and a text input to filter them. If you type in the text input, it should check for what you typed against the country name, which should return the new filtered list of countries that match the filtered text. It should also display the inputted text next to `Typed Text:`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, Text, TextInput } from 'react-native'
import { observable, action } from 'mobx';
import { observer } from 'mobx-react/native'

@observer
export default class Country extends Component {
    @observable filterTermValue;
    @observable countriesList = [
      {'slug': 'amsterdam', 'name': 'Amsterdam'},
      {'slug': 'usa', 'name': 'United States'},
      {'slug': 'vienna', 'name': 'Vienna'}
    ];

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>Typed Text: {this.filterTermValue}</Text>
                <TextInput placeholder="Start typing country"
                   value={this.filterTermValue}
                   onChange={this.onChangeFilterTerm} />

                {this.countriesList.map(country =>
                    <View key={country.slug}>
                      <Text>{country.name}</Text>
                    </View>
                )}
            </View>
        )
    }

    @action onChangeFilterTerm = (e) => {
        this.filterTermValue = e.target.value;

        this.countriesList.replace(this.countriesList.filter(el => el.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.filterTermValue.toLowerCase()) > -1));
    }
}
```

That's all the logic I have and I can't get it to work. The only thing that works is the country list loads the original array. Once I start typing in the input, the value is undefined and never prints, and the list is never filtered. I also tried `async` actions and `runInAction` I even tried computed to return the filtered list, but can't seem to get it to work.

What is the right way to do this in mobX?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I saw a few possible problems, so I slightly changed the approach.

#### Working example

**UPDATED** [Working example](http://jsbin.com/gadozi/19/edit?js,output). Note this is untested in `react-native`, but it should work.

#### The code

```
@observer
class Country extends React.Component {


    @observable filterTermValue = '';
    @observable countriesList = [
      {'slug': 'amsterdam', 'name': 'Amsterdam'},
      {'slug': 'usa', 'name': 'United States'},
      {'slug': 'vienna', 'name': 'Vienna'}
    ];

    @computed get filtered() {
      let filteredList = this.countriesList.filter(
        t=>t.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.filterTermValue)>-1
      );
      if (filteredList.length)
        return filteredList;
      return this.countriesList;
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <div>
              Term: <input placeholder="Start typing country"
                 onKeyUp={this.onChangeFilterTerm} />

              {this.filtered.map(country =>
                  <div key={country.slug}>
                    <p>{country.name}</p>
                  </div>
              )}
          </div>
        )
    }

    @action onChangeFilterTerm = value => {
        this.filterTermValue = value.toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

#### React-native gotchyas

**Use `onChangeText` correct signature**

jsx:

```
    <input placeholder="Start typing country"
            onKeyUp={this.onChangeFilterTerm} />
```

js:

```
    @action onChangeFilterTerm = value => {
        this.filterTermValue = value.toLowerCase();
    }
```

**Use `mobx-react/native`**

If its still not working, I would double check this:

Dont:

```
import {observer} from 'mobx-react';
```

Do:

```
import {observer} from 'mobx-react/native';
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, even though the jsbin works, I am trying to only use mobx for state management, instead of rn's this.state and this.setState. Trying to replace them with mobX observers, but not sure why it won't work. I think it should be possible to totally replace rn's state handling for this view with pure mobx. Any idea if it's possible?

Comment: Oh doh! I wasn't really thinking when I was clearning up the jsbin haha!  let me have a look

Comment: Ok that should be what you are after!

Comment: Thanks again - it almost works in React, but if I type `am` it works, `amv` it shows all 3 instead of being empty.. Also, in RN I change the `TextInput` to have `value={this.filterTermValue} onChange={this.onChangeFilterTerm}` instead of `keyUp` but I get the red error screen saying `Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined` pointing to the @action's e.target.value. I also tried to change it to `onChange={this.onChangeFilterTerm.bind(this)}` but still same error. Not sure why it's not working in RN!

Comment: Updated!. ReactNative uses `onChangeText` according to the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html) :)

Comment: Thanks Ash and yup - I tried both `onChange={this.onChangeFilterTerm}` / `onChange={this.onChangeFilterTerm.bind(this)}` and `onChangeText={this.onChangeFilterTerm}` / `onChangeText={this.onChangeFilterTerm.bind(this)}` and I keep getting the same `Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined pointing to the @action's e.target.value` No clue why it's not passing it! Will try for a bit longer!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114903/discussion-between-ashley-coolman-and-wonka).

Comment: Ashley Coolman said in the chat: "If you check the docs for TextInput, you can see the function signature for onChangeText does not pass an event ({target: {value: "Some text"...}...}), it pass the string itself ("Some text"). Updated with code of what I think this will look like (untested)"
Wonla said: "
Ash, it works! "