# Filtering Observable arrays

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I am following up on this question: [mobX - Filter countries in react native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37865454/mobx-filter-countries-in-react-native)

In my own application, I am attaching my mobx observable object to a firebase store.

I have managed to get working to the point I can list and delete the values I get from the store, it is when trying to filter I get a problem. Here's the code:

```html
import React from 'react';
import {map} from 'lodash';
import { observable, computed } from 'mobx';
import { observer } from 'mobx-react';
import {todos} from '../../store/todos/todos';

@observer
export class TodosListComponent extends React.Component {

  del = (id) => {
    todos.del(id)
  };


@observable sampleArray = [
      {'name': 'Amsterdam'},
      {'name': 'United States'},
      {'name': 'Vienna'}
    ];


  @observable filterTermValue = '';
  @computed get filtered() {
      let filteredList = this.sampleArray.filter(
        t=>t.name.indexOf(this.filterTermValue)>-1
      );
      if (filteredList.length)
        return filteredList;
      return todos.json;


    }

  render() {
    return (
        <ul>
          {map(this.filtered, (it, key) => (
                  <li onClick={this.del.bind(this, key)}
                      key={key}>{it.name}</li>)
          )}
        </ul>
    )
  }
}
```

You see if I filter the mock sampleArray I created in my filtered() function, it will work (except with the fake data).

And if I try to filter the json object I get an error stating that filter is not a function.

Is the best way of filtering my store result to convert it to a js array? If that's the case, how do you go about that?

Here is the store code:

```html
import {observable, computed} from 'mobx';
import {Fb} from '../../firebase/firebase-store';
import {map, toJS} from 'mobx';

class Todos {
  

  constructor() {
    Fb.todos.on('value', (snapshot) => {
      this.todos = snapshot.val();
    });
  }

  @computed get json() {
    return toJS(this.todos);
  }

  add = (name) => {
    const id = Fb.todos.push().key;
    this.update(id, name);
  };

  update = (id, name) => {
    Fb.todos.update({[id]: {name}})
  };

  del = (id) => {
    Fb.todos.child(id).remove();
  };
}

const todos = new Todos();
export {todos};
```

I should say that although I am a real self tought noob in the matter, I have tried long and hard before asking this question.

Appreciate any help,
Thanks!

Comment: Could you include your entire component/store? It is hard to say what is wrong from the code in your question.

Comment: Just updated it now with the store code! Thanks for your time.

Comment: You extend `React.Component`, but you don't have a `render` method. You then create an instance and export that. It looks like you have mixed it up a bit.

Comment: Yea, I've been trying all sorts of different iterations but I do see your point. I'll clean it up and try another approach and see if I have better results - thanks!

Comment: @Throlle If you'll indulge me once more, I have updated my question - would appreciate your comment.

Comment: Interesting. It might be that your `todos` is just a JSON string. Try `@observable todos = JSON.parse(todoJson);` or however your todos are created.

Comment: I'm trying to implement your suggestion (so far with no luck) - meanwhile I added the store code for your perusal. Again, really appreciate the help.

Comment: You probably want an observable array and push the snapshot to it instead, or replace it. `@observable todos = [];` outside constructor, `Fb.todos.on('value', snapshot => this.todos.push(snapshot.val()));` inside constructor. I have no experience with firebase, so I'm not sure. You probably want to use the MobX array instead of using toJS.

Comment: Turns out the issue was in firebase and i was staring at the wrong place.

The snapshot allows for quite a bit of querying and I have just found the documentation available: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/11/firebase-now-with-more-querying.html

Thanks for the help, man - you helped me steer in the right direction.

Excelsior!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem wasn't in the array or an observable object - but the fact that the store data was coming from a firebase snapshot.

I found this 2014 article by its founder explaining the basics of the snapshot's querying and after a quick read I managed to get it working.

Here's the relevant piece of code:

```html
Fb.todos.orderByChild("name").equalTo("whattosearchforhere").on('value', (snapshot) => {
      this.todos = snapshot.val();
    });
```

Excelsior!